# Continue after reuters has retrieved data

Tags: vba, excel, reuters

**Thomson Reuters Eikon used:**

I need to get data from reuters regarding fx spot prices. This is easily done with a reuters formula. However, I need to use this data in a VBA script. Part of the VBA script inserts the formula, reuters then retrieves data but this can take a while (10-20 seconds).

How do i make the VBA script pause until reuters has retrieved the data? (in the first 10 seconds the cell of the reuters data says: 'retrieving....'

```
Range("B2").value = Application.Evaluate("RtGet(" & IDN & "," & RWAL & "," & MIDPRICE & "," & TYPENUM & ")")
```

This code is now used to insert the formula where RWAL is the exchange rate identifier (such as EUR=)

Comment: You can make a `Do While` loop which will repeat something like `Sleep 1000` until value of cell changes (compared to previous value stored in a variable).

Comment: Sleep (and wait) hold up the whole excel right? So that would mean that the formula also stops trying to retrieve reuters data.

Comment: Do you only need a one time snapshot of the prices or do you need the prices continuously streaming into your Excel sheet?. The function `RtGet()` is for the latter scenario. Also please update your question with what desktop software you are using (e.g. *Reuters 3000 Xtra* or *Thomson Reuters Eikon*).

Comment: I needa one time snapshot at current time (and they way i get this now is by streaming and then copy paste value). I use Thomson Reuters Eikon

Comment: If you do coding, you might better you proprietary Thomson Reuters data access interfaces like AdxRtList for realtime data.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use application.run to use the RtGet function in code as its really a worksheet function. Because its a worksheet function, the data will not be retrieved while code is running.

To get round this we use Application.RTD.RefreshData to pull the data from the RTD server

```
Function getField(ric As String, field As String) As String
    Data = Application.Run("RtGet", "IDN", ric, field)
    Do While VBA.Left(CStr(Data), 3) = "Ret" 'ie loop while it is retrieving data
        Application.RTD.RefreshData
        DoEvents
        Data = Application.Run("RtGet", "IDN", ric, field)
        Debug.Print Data
    Loop
    getField = Data
End Function

Public Sub testGetField()
    Dim test
    test = getField("EUR=", "BID")
End Sub
```